# Can the energy of the universe ever be infinite in qunatum physics?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, cosmology, universe

Suppose that the universe runs under some variants of QFT, with universal wavefunction and Hamiltonian. Then would infinite energy of the universe ever be possible? According to what I am thinking, this would cause problems with Hamiltonian...

Comment: Potential energy is scalable. You can zero it at infinity and then the energy of the universe becomes infinite in the equations.... There's a sentence I though I'd never say; "zero it at infinity"

Answer (score 1):

The Universe is infinite. If the energy density of the universe is greater than zero, then the total energy must also be infinite.

Comment: but then what happens to universal wavefunction? Do we have to assume that such wavefunction does not exist? Otherwise, Hamiltonian will produce eigenvalue that explodes... (Or maybe we define vacuum as having infinite energy and Hamiltonian as exciting over it?)